# Sort a pandas's dataframe series by month and year?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am very new to python and using pandas and am struggling with working with time.

I have a dataframe that contains the date that different events took place. I want to bin/sort the events in terms of when they occured in time (month and year). Each Event has a corresponding count of one. I want to sort the data in time and get the sum of events that occur in each month. The code I have used to try this is shown below.

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Date')
all_events_dates=df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B %Y'))['Count'].sum()
month_year = ['January 2013','February 2013','March 2013', 'April 2013','May 2013','June 2013','July 2013','August 2013','September 2013','October 2013','November 2013','December 2013','January 2014','February 2014','March 2014', 'April 2014','May 2014','June 2014','July 2014','August 2014','September 2014','October 2014','November 2014','December 2014','January 2015','February 2015','March 2015', 'April 2015','May 2015','June 2015','July 2015','August 2015','September 2015','October 2015','November 2015','December 2015']
all_events_dates.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(set(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B %Y')), categories=month_year, ordered=True)
all_events_dates = all_events_dates.sort_index()
print(all_events_dates)
```

The output from this is as follows (cutting out some of the months):

```
-January 2013       2
-February 2013      6
-March 2013        12
-April 2013        11
-May 2013           2
-June 2013          4
-July 2013          2
-September 2013     1
...
-August 2015        3
-September 2015     8
-October 2015       7
-November 2015      4
-December 2015      2
```

Which is incorrectly binned (the frequency per month is incorrect). And when I open a new project and wanted to attempt the same thing but instead of sorting in terms of event I was going to sort in terms of a location in time I used this code:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Date')
all_loc_dates=df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B %Y'))['Count'].sum()
month_year = ['January 2013','February 2013','March 2013', 'April 2013','May 2013','June 2013','July 2013','August 2013','September 2013','October 2013','November 2013','December 2013','January 2014','February 2014','March 2014', 'April 2014','May 2014','June 2014','July 2014','August 2014','September 2014','October 2014','November 2014','December 2014','January 2015','February 2015','March 2015', 'April 2015','May 2015','June 2015','July 2015','August 2015','September 2015','October 2015','November 2015','December 2015']
all_loc_dates.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(set(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B %Y')), categories=month_year, ordered=True)
all_loc_dates = all_loc_dates.sort_index()
print(all_loc_dates)
```

Which appears to be the same code, but I get the following output:

```
January 2013       9
February 2013      1
March 2013         7
April 2013         7
May 2013           4
June 2013          9
July 2013          4
September 2013    10
October 2013       1
November 2013      8
December 2013      5
...
June 2015          4
July 2015          2
August 2015       12
September 2015     4
October 2015       3
November 2015      2
December 2015      2
```

The df in both cases is the same (just in different projects). I am unsure of why the freqencies per month per year would be different and incorrect?

I have found that the problem appears to be in the following lines of code:

```
all_loc_dates.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(set(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B %Y')), categories=month_year, ordered=True)
all_loc_dates = all_loc_dates.sort_index()
```

The correct output is given when these lines are excluded. Though the ordering is incorrect. The output is as follows:

```
April 2013         4
April 2014         4
April 2015         7
August 2014        5
August 2015        6
December 2013      2
December 2014      3
December 2015     10
February 2013      4
February 2014      4
February 2015      3
January 2013       7
January 2014       8
January 2015       5
...
September 2013     2
September 2014     1
September 2015     3
```

These appear to be the correct values but of course are now ordered incorrectly. Not sure why the pd.CategoricalIndex function was changing the values. Also how would one sort the series in terms of date if not using this function?

Comment: Should Mention that I read the data in from an excel file.

Comment: can you show your input and expected output?

Comment: Would be great, if you share a sample xlsx file.

Comment: I found that it is a problem with the pd.CategoricalIndex function and not the excel file which I suspected at first. Since unsure what the issue is but I will post if I get a solution.

Comment: Take a look at the `pandas.df.resample` method, it might be just what you need.

Comment: Hi Engels, had a look at the resample method and I'm sure this will work for my data as well, just I found another approach similar to what taga posted below. Thank you for advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your month name to month number, for example Jan 2013 to 01 2013.
Then sort it, and then change it again to month name-year.

```
df['date value'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date value'], format='%b%Y')

df = df.sort_values('date value', ascending = True)
```

Comment: thanks, can you please upvote my answer and confirm it?

Comment: hey taga I upvoted it but its not shown as my reputation is less than 15!

Comment: No problem my friend